# The constructor Vehicle(String[], int) is undefined

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm very new with java and can't figure this out!
this is how it should look like , but it gives me an error and i'm not sure if i have to convert it or not !
or i'm doing something else wrong!!!

here is my requirements:
Assign values to variables using the provided vehicle data. Refer to the Data File Layout Information for information of accessing these vehicle data values.
                      1. speeds

```
public class Bicycle extends Vehicle implements IOutput {

private static int speeds;

public Bicycle(String[] vehicleData) {
    super(vehicleData,speeds);   // get error: The constructor Vehicle(String[], int) is undefined

            // or i should this one :
    speeds = Convert.toInteger(vehicleData[0]);
}
```

here is the vehicle class

```
public Vehicle(String[] vehicleData) {
    count++;
    owner= new Owner(vehicleData);

    setVehicleType(Convert.toInteger(vehicleData[0]));
    make = vehicleData[1];
    model = vehicleData[2];
    color = vehicleData[3];
    purchaseDate = vehicleData[4];
    cost = Convert.toDouble(vehicleData[5]);
}
```

Comment: ...the error (and fix) is self-explanatory, where is the confusion!?

Comment: yes, but i have to also meet my requirement:   Assign values to variables using the provided vehicle data. Refer to the Data File Layout Information for information of accessing these vehicle data values.
1. speeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super` is calling the `Vehicle` constructor, which accepts only a String, not a String and a int.

Change to this.

```
// remove static
int speed;
public Bicycle(String[] vehicleData) {
    super(vehicleData);
    speeds = Integer.valueOf(vehicleData[0]);
}
```

Comment: Not how you were calling the base constructor.

Answer (score 4):

your constructor in your Vehicle class accepts only string[] and you are passing a string[] and an int.

change

```
super(vehicleData,speeds);   // get error: The constructor Vehicle(String[], int) is undefined
```

to

```
super(vehicleData);   // your error'd now disappear
```

or declare speeds in your super class **Vehicle**.

```
int speed;
public Vehicle(String[] vehicleData, int speed)
```

Comment: @user1834534 your super class constructor doesnt accept it. define it in your super class as well.

Comment: but i can't! my professor has created UML without that :( what else i can do in my bicycle class?